# Escaping a pair of orbiting black holes through the saddle

Tags: science-based, physics, gravity, orbital-mechanics, black-holes

Imagine a pair of black holes in orbit around each other. I'm wondering how this would distort their mutual event horizons. In fact would it be possible to "break" the event horizons by reducing the escape velocity below the speed of light at the point in between the two holes.

If my mental model is right there would be a saddle point in between the two holes. In theory you could climb out of the hole up to the mid point of the saddle where the red dot is and then turn and climb up the ridge to escape entirely.

[image: saddle point]

Would this work given the right pair of black holes in the right circumstances?

If not then what stops it?

Comment: It'll work fine if the pilot screams "Yee Hawwww..!" at the top of his/her voice during the manoeuvre.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying this while piloting an [indestructable piece of farmyard equipment](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-trouble-with-ftl-588cb3a3a03c#.qft9gv4m9)?

Comment: aren't you, before reaching the red dot, still in the region where escape velocity is higher than c?

Comment: @L.Dutch Well that's the question really :)

Comment: @JoeBloggs That can be arranged.

Comment: Check out "The Maw" in the Star Wars universe. It is right about what you want. What Han Solo did to make the "Kessel Run" in less than 12 parsecs (DISTANCE) was to daredevilishly fly the MF very close to the centroid of both black holes.

Comment: Inside the event horizon the direction towards the black hole is timelike, that is, the future means being closer to the black hole, and being farther from the black hole is in the past. You cannot move from closer to the black hole to farther away from the black hole anymore than you can move from being farther away from the Jurassic to being closer to it... Or at least that's what I believe to have understood, and would welcome any better news.

Comment: The problem with your mental model is the steepness of the slope. The slope only gets steeper as you get deeper into the 'hole.' If you are already past the part where you can't get out, any direction you can possibly move takes you to another region where you can't get out. Once you pass the event horizon, you will have to be going faster than the speed of light to get back onto the saddle, so you aren't going to get there.

Comment: @kingledion Except that the proximity of the other black hole "pulls down" the slope of the first one. At some point if A and B are approaching each other their gravity wells will merge. That means that at some point there is a way to pass from one to the other. The question is whether at any point the slope out of that "valley" is less than the speed of light.

Comment: @TimB That is what I am saying, the slope of the black hole is such that you cannot move to an area with lower slope. So even if the saddle is 'pulled down,' the speed needed to get there from a point 'higher up' on the non-saddle portions is greater than the speed of light. Another way to view it is, if you travelled around the lip of the black hole towards the saddle, by the time you got to the saddle you would have been pulled so far down the hole that you can no longer get out.

Comment: See [my question on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318869/can-tides-be-raised-on-a-black-hole) on this general topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So . . . modeling the space near two close black holes is actually a really, really tough task. Numerical relativity is extremely challenging; a good example is the intense computations it took to finally create an excellent simulation of [GW150914](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves), the source of the first directly detected gravitational waves. Therefore, determining the exact behavior of the event horizons quantitatively is a non-trivial problem.

That said, it's certainly not an impossible problem, and numerical relativists have performed simulations of [the shape of binary black hole event horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole#Shape). A good set of visualizations is given in [Cohen et al. (2011)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1668v1). See, for instance, Figures 8 and 9:

[image: Simulated images showing event horizons getting closer together]

The caption for Figure 8:

> A snapshot of the geodesics being followed by the event horizon ﬁnder at time $t/M = t_{\text{merger}}/M − 0.067$, for the equal-mass inspiral. The small dots are geodesics currently on the event horizon. The larger points, either crosses or circles, represent geodesics in the process of merging onto the event horizon. Crosses represent points merging through caustic points, while circles represent points merging through crossovers. In this slice, the cusp on the black hole is linear, and composed of crossover points with caustics at the end points.

Figure 9 shows the geodesics at $t/M = t_{\text{merger}}/M$, where $M$ is mass and $t_{\text{merger}}$ is the time at which the black holes merge. These simulations show how distorted the event horizons become as they are elongated until they form a thin bridge. Merging and [ringdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole#Ringdown) soon follow.

What I *think* you're suggesting is that at precisely $t = t_{\text{merger}}$, there is a point where the event horizons touch, and that at the point it may be possible to travel on some other path and avoid both black holes entirely. The literal answer is that this is impossible.

Remember that an [event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon) is a region of spacetime from within which no event can be causally connected to any event outside the horizon. You'd have to travel faster than the speed of light to escape, and, of course, that's impossible. If an object is on or inside the event horizon, it doesn't matter whether it's on some saddle point, as you called it. There's no way out. That node is still, as perhaps [Admiral Ackbar would put it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F4qzPbcFiA), a trap.

Obviously, if the object begins at that point *before* either of the event horizons reach it, then the answer is trivial: Yes, it can escape. It would just have to go really, really, really fast (subluminally). But the event horizons would not be "broken".

A very similar question on Physics Stack Exchange is [Event Horizon violability?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1134/56299) See also [Is it possible for one black hole to pull an object out of another black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39253/56299).